# asp.net miscelenius error provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

When starting the application, everything goes well and a query is done to the server with no problems.

Once I click on a link that requires another connection to the Sql Server 2008 express R2, I get an error :

Une erreur liée au réseau ou spécifique à l'instance s'est produite lors de l'établissement d'une connexion à SQL Server. Le serveur est introuvable ou n'est pas accessible. Vérifiez que le nom de l'instance est correct et que SQL Server est configuré pour autoriser les connexions distantes. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Impossible d'ouvrir une connexion à SQL Server)

The problem does not happens on the server : www.jbusinesses.com

Any one can help ? 
I tried almost everything and everything seems to be ok since the first cinnection seems to be good, its only on a second connection the problem shows itself...

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error when you can't reach your sql database server.

The the server name and instance in the second connection string.

Test if you can connect to that server from SqlServer management studio.

Also check if a firewall is blocking connections to that particular sql server.